# Legality of the use of commercial fonts available for free from uxfree.com

Tags: intellectual-property, licensing

I am interested in using the Futura PT family of fonts in a web application for the company at which I work.  I initially found Futura PT listed on fonts.google.com, but the font wasn't available for free as it just had a link to monotype.com where it could be purchased.

However, I found Futura PT on a website called UXfree ([link to download page](https://www.uxfree.com/dload/462559/)) where I could just download it for free.  Would this free version be legal to use internally at a company?  An outside company made our company's public facing website, which uses the Futura PT fonts, and I don't know how they licensed it.  I was hoping to use Futura PT in the web application to give a look consistent with our public website, which in turn is consistent with our branding.

Can I legally use this freely downloaded commercial font in a non-public web application the company will use internally?  Or am I required to purchase it?

Comment: What does the website's license say?

Comment: I don't really understand the legalese.  I sent a message to them asking about it.  At least they won't downvote me there :)  I will post the answer to my question here though in case it helps anyone.

Comment: If it's any consolation - people downvote here because they don't appreciate the gaps in knowledge of the question askers.  It's a common problem across all SE sites.  On the stack overflow site it's a massive problem that prevents new members joining the site.

Comment: @DanRayson Appreciate the comment, and yes, I have seen how it's a problem on Stack Overflow too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a message to Monotype about this matter.  Here is what I wrote:

> I found Futura PT from fonts.google.com which sent me to fonts.com where I could buy Futura PT for $30.  However, I found the font available at this site: https://www.uxfree.com/dload/462559/
>   Are they violating the law by providing the Futura PT font for free?

And here was the response:

> Yes, they most probably are - thanks for making us aware of it. We will forward this to our legal department.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy something from a thief, you don’t own it - it doesn’t matter that what the thief stole was intellectual rather than physical property.